# Communicating structs as array of bytes

Tags: c++, memcpy

On an school project, we have a system composed of embedded systems, XBee modules and a server, all of which (will) communicate data that is organized in `struct`s between each other. My idea is to serialize the data in an array, something the modules can understand, send this array and rebuild the `struct` on the other side.

We use C++ (no C++11) in our design and sometimes the `struct`s will contain `std::string`s and `std::vector`s for convenience. I have been trying to send the structures, for example between two Xbee modules, as C-style arrays of `char`s. So far, I have:

```
// From C:
#include<string.h>

// From C++:
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>


// A Project related struct:
struct A
{
    std::string              name;
    std::vector<std::string> hobbies;
};

int main()
{
    // Instantiate an object:
    A a;
    a.name    = "John";
    a.hobbies = {"hobby1", "hobby2"};

    // Get the actual size of a, in bytes:
    const size_t N = sizeof(a);

    // Create a table of chars, big enough to accommodate 'a', It
    // is this I want to communicate:
    char buffer[N];

    // Copy 'a' to 'buffer', byte-wise:
    memcpy(buffer, &a, N);

    // Retreive information:
    A b;
    memcpy(&b, buffer, N); // <-- This line causing segfault.

    std::cout << b.name << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code segfaults. It has led me to do some more research on the topic and I have found that this method only works for structures containing only C-style types. What I haven't found is how to achieve my communication.

How could I do it?

Comment: Of course the line is causing a segmentation fault. You are illegally acessing memory. If you want to serialize the data use some language built-in construct, I don't know of any. But certainly having a `std::string` in the array will be a problem, because classe are not only data but also methods and other things AFAIK. So if you want to serialize the data, don't use any `std::string` or `std::vector` or use a native serializer which might exist. Also, may be you meant `memcpy(buffer, &a, sizeof(a));` but I doubt that will work.

Comment: Don't use `memcpy` for anything that contains copy-constructors (like your structure does). It most likely won't copy what you think it should copy. In your case the *contents* of the string and vector will not be copied at all.

Comment: You can't just `memcpy` a `string` and hope that it will work. `string` contains pointers to separately allocated memory which won't be copied by `memcpy`. You can copy an object only if it is [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable). If it is not, you have to serialize it.

Comment: Yes as all have told you, serialization in c++ is not trivial except for POD types, [read here to understand better](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).

Comment: @Ron Certainly a typo, nothing mysterious.

Comment: So there is no way to do this with `string`s and `vector`s without diving into deeper serialization techniques... I understand, thanks!